# Domain Specific Languages in software reuse

Tags: dsl, code-reuse

I would like to ask about the advantages of using Domain Specific Languages vs software libraries in software reuse research.

I have read some papers stating that using DSLs is a better approach than using software libraries for software reuse field but without mentioning many reasons.

One reason I read is that DSLs receive direct support from compiler while software libraries do not, I could not understand this issue also.

Regards

Comment: This question is not a good fit for SO ([FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)). Furthermore, *"I have read some papers stating"* really needs references.

Comment: Introduction to Software Reuse
Jacob L. Cybulski  ,, also in the introduction of this paper regarding compiler use ,, http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~lin/papers/dsl99.pdf

Comment: A short answer: DSLs are retargetable. This property is important for all the aspects of maintainability, not just the reuse. Another trait: DSLs are combineable (if there is a proper infrastructure in place). You much less depend on a platform, a language and libraries with DSLs than if you're using the "normal" libraries and frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You should read James Neighbor's [papers on Draco](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~cs309/references/Neighbors_Draco.pdf) for an eye-opening view of "code" (generation knowledge) reuse and DSLs.

Jim is the guy who *invented* the term "domain analysis".

The fundamental lesson is that reuse of construction knowledge is more powerful than reuse of code libraries, yet easier to use for the domain expert.

Me? I just use the stuff.